# Incompatibility of thmtools, IEEEtrantools, and cleveref in Tex Live 2018-2019

Tags: ieeetran, cleveref, thmtools, texlive-2018, texlive-2019

Using TeX Live 2018 or 2019, `IEEEtrantools`, `thmtools` and `cleveref` are incompatible. I.e., if one loads these packages together, the project does not compile. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

The error goes away when one removes any one of those three packages. The three packages were compatible in TeX Live 2017. Is there a way to make these three packages compatible in TeX Live 2018-2019 or is it now necessary to chose only two of them for each project?

Comment: Load `IEEEtrantools` after the other two packages.

Comment: Or rather, don't load `cleverref` as the last package of these three. The other combinations work; at least, they compile.

Comment: That works. Thanks very much.

Comment: Wait, the cleveref document (p. 4) says that, to work properly, cleveref should be loaded last. See here: http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.pdf . This makes your suggestion dangerous.

Comment: Therefore I wrote `at least, they compile`. `cleveref` contains conditional code that is executed if  `IEEEtrantools` has been loaded, which it can only detect if it is loaded last. In any case, `cleveref` is the only package that has changed in 2018, the other two are still old.

Comment: There are always exceptions

Comment: @daleif Confucius?

Comment: I've sent a bug report to the author of `cleveref`.